# What is the equivalent of Container.GetAllInstances<T> in NInject?

Tags: dependency-injection, ioc-container, ninject

I'm building a message broker with NInject, and I need to find all instances in the container that implement Consumes, an interface that marks the class as being able to consume a particular message type.

Is this scenario supported?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer from Nate:

> Multi-resolution (via `GetAll`) is
>   currently not polymorphic. That means
>   that it will only consider bindings
>   from the exact interface you specify.
>   If you do this:
>
> ```
> kernel.Bind<IWorker>().To<WorkerA>();
> kernel.Bind<IWorker>().To<WorkerB>();
> kernel.Bind<IWorker>().To<WorkerC>();
> ```
>
> And then:
>
> ```
> kernel.GetAll<IWorker>();
> ```
>
> It will return 3 items. However, even
>   if `IWorkerA`, `IWorkerB`, and
>   `IWorkerC` implement `IWorker`,
>   Ninject will not look at bindings from
>   `IWorkerA` to `WorkerA` when you ask
>   for `IWorker`.

See :

http://groups.google.com/group/ninject/browse_thread/thread/7b6afa06099bc97a#

Answer (score 1):

If you if you don't have the polymorphic situation as discussed in the thread that is referenced by [Romain's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394697/what-is-the-equivalent-of-container-getallinstancest-in-ninject/1394758#1394758), then you shouldn't have any issues as long as you are using Ninject 2.  Ninject 1.x did not include this sort of support.